# creating a slack calls response for a slash command

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

When i try to send a calls response after acknowledgement using `@slack/bolt` library it gives me 500 internal server error.

```
app.command('/interview', async ({ command, ack, respond }) => {
await ack();

await respond({
    "response_type":"call",
    "call_initiation_url":"https://example.com/"
});
}
```

what might be the issue in the respond request ?

Comment: Are you posting your response to the `response_url` that you get from the slash command payload?

Comment: yes this respond function from bolt does that internally